# Difference between agg(sqlmax) and agg(max) in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In a pyspark program, I read the following line of code. What exactly does this line try to achieve? What's the difference between `sqlmax` and `max` in pyspark?

```
df.groupBy('groupId').agg(sqlmax('Time').alias('MaxTime')).withColumnRenamed('groupid1','groupid2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `sqlmax` is imported as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as sqlmax
```

which kind of makes sense if the author of the code wanted to avoid overwriting the Python `max` function. You can't use the Python `max` in the `agg`, but you can use the Spark SQL `max` aggregation.

A perhaps  more common way to write this is to do

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupBy('groupId').agg(F.max('Time').alias('MaxTime'))
```